# I want to get data from user and insert into db (SQL)

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class NewTry {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String dep,namee,cnic,cell;
        int id;
            id=Integer.parseInt(txtTeacherId.getText());
            namee=txtTeacherName.getText();
            dep=cmbDepName.getSelectedItem().toString();
            cnic=txtTeacherCnicNo.getText();
            cell=txtTeacherCellNo.getText();
            try
            {
//               try
//                  {
//                    // create a mysql database connection
//                    String myDriver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
//                    String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
//                    Class.forName(myDriver);
//                    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test", "root", "");
//                    

                //Class.forname("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test", "root", "");
                //  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,n); 
                String insertSql = "INSERT INTO Teacher VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                PreparedStatement pInsertTeacher = conn.prepareStatement(insertSql);
             //   pInsertTeacher=conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TEACHER VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
                pInsertTeacher.setInt(1,id);
                pInsertTeacher.setString(2,namee);
                pInsertTeacher.setString(3,dep);
                pInsertTeacher.setString(4,cnic);
                pInsertTeacher.setString(5,cell);

                pInsertTeacher.executeUpdate();

                //preparedStmt.execute();
                System.out.println("Data inserted Successfully Check your SQL table");
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record Already Inserted....");
            }
    }
}
```

I want to take input from user and save into sql db. but i am unable make my desired code.
There are error that is receive by run this code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
txtTeacherId cannot be resolved
txtTeacherName cannot be resolved
cmbDepName cannot be resolved
txtTeacherCnicNo cannot be resolved
txtTeacherCellNo cannot be resolved
at NewTry.main(NewTry.java:17)
```

Comment: where is your user interaction form??

Comment: You didn't declare any of "Teacher" fields.

Comment: What is you understanding of the error message?

Comment: Seems this is strong incomplete / ruined swing project? Do You edit in IDE, simple editor, or copy fragments from clipboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is basically not compile-able.  On lines

```
id=Integer.parseInt(txtTeacherId.getText());
namee=txtTeacherName.getText();
dep=cmbDepName.getSelectedItem().toString();
cnic=txtTeacherCnicNo.getText();
cell=txtTeacherCellNo.getText();
```

you are using variables which have not been declared at all. Try

```
Console c = System.console();
id=Integer.parseInt(c.readLine("Insert teacher ID: "));
namee=c.readLine("Insert teacher name: ");
dep=c.readLine("Insert teacher department: ");
cnic=c.readLine("Insert teacher cnic: ");
cell=c.readLine("Insert teacher cell: ");
```

instead. Of course if you want to use user interface for defining the data, you should go for a Java AWT, Java SWING or Java FX tutorials.